# Cabinets Installed Directly on Slab?

Tags: installation, cabinets, moisture, slab

I just had some cabinets installed in my kitchen directly on the concrete slab foundation, and the installer didn't use any moisture barrier or anything comparable to ensure the wood products avoid contact with the slab. My concern is that wood products in direct contact with the slab will wick up moisture over time leading to weakening of the plywood cabinet box. Is this a legitimate concern?

I mean I've seen untreated wood in contact with a slab rot away, and I know nowadays builders use treated wood for the lower part of framing that's in contact with the slab to avoid this issue. Also don't we always use a moisture barrier under hardwood flooring?

After calling around to several other installers, there seems to be a 50/50 split disagreement on this - half think it's fine to install directly on the slab, the other half say there needs to be isolation.

So can we settle this? Is it ok to install wood products directly on the slab? If not, how would you isolate the cabinets from the slab? Using composite shims all around would seem to provide a compromised foundation for the cabinets and countertop.

I live in Houston, the slab sits on grade, the home was built in 1977...

Comment: Is there a vapor barrier _under_ the slab? If so, that should isolate it from the ground leaving minimal moisture to wick through to the cabinets themselves. That said, I'd bet all the installers know you should put some sort of barrier, but some are interested in future business replacing warped, rotten, soggy cabinetry.

Comment: No, we can't settle this. It depends largely on 1) climate, 2) ground water situation, 3) whether there's anything under the slab, 4) local code, 5) cabinet maker warranty requirements, and on and on. There's no one answer. That said, wood in contact with concrete is required to be treated where I am, and cabinets are never treated. No finish woodwork is.

Comment: What does your cabinet maker say? That's a clear concern to me.

Comment: Around here, for the last 20 years, cabinets are on plastic legs, which are then turned to adjust the height. Are you sure that your cabinets touch the floor?